# Calculated field in a header table that sums values from a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building a simple project database that holds data about foods and recipes. Recipes exist in the recipe header table that stores one row per recipe with basic overview and the recipe detail table stores rows for all ingredients that make up a recipe. What I want to achieve is a calculated column that shows the total number of calories per recipe.

I can get the total number of calories using the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(calories) FROM products pd
INNER JOIN recipe_detail rd ON pd.id = rd.product_id
WHERE rd.recipe_id = 1
```

This will get me the total calories for the first recipe. The problem is, I store the nutritional data in the products table for a specific number of grams (Usually 100g) whereas the recipe might need only 50g of a product. How do I adjust this query so that I would get a fraction of the calories I need?

I basically need to take the gram value of a product that belongs in a recipe, divide it by the gram value in the products table to get the ratio and then multiply that by the number of calories to get the answer.

Comment: Please show us a few records of sample data from both tables and the associated expected result in order to clarifiy your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the names and types of your columns or how your information is stored exactly, but I think this might help:

```sql
SELECT r.*, SUM((p.calories * rd.weight) / p.weight::numeric) AS calories -- depending on the types of your columns, you can omit the cast; I added it to be sure it is not integer division
FROM recipe r
INNER JOIN recipe_detail rd ON rd.recipe_id = r.id
INNER JOIN porducts p ON p.id = rd.product_id
GROUP BY r.id
```